# Como obtener la SUMA de una tabla?

Tags: sql-server

Como saco la suma de la columna PUNTOS a partir de la selección de un Usuario numero X cuya fecha tenga el Mes 6 por Ejemplo:

```
+---------+--------+--------------------------------------+
| Usuario | Puntos |         Fecha                        |
+---------+--------+--------------------------------------+
|  252    | 550    | 2020-08-29 00:30:06.000              |
+---------+--------+--------------------------------------+
|  252    | 450    | 2020-06-23 13:14:06.000              |
+---------+--------+--------------------------------------+
|  252    | 250    | 2020-06-08 15:08:06.000              |
+---------+--------+--------------------------------------+
|  254    | 250    | 2020-06-26 01:15:06.000              |
+---------+--------+--------------------------------------+
```

Pensé que seria algo así pero no me sale nada:

```
SELECT (SUM(Puntos)) as Suma FROM DB.dbo.mitabla 
WHERE Usuario  = 252
AND Fecha IN (SELECT MONTH(GETDATE()))
```

Comment: ¿No sería `MONTH(Fecha) = 6`?

Answer (score 2):

El problema es que estás comparando una fecha con un entero (`Fecha IN (SELECT MONTH(GETDATE())`), al comparar meses (un entero) lo debes hacer en ambos lados de la igualdad:

```
SELECT SUM(Puntos) as Suma 
FROM DB.dbo.mitabla 
WHERE Usuario  = 252
AND MONTH(Fecha) = MONTH(GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 1):

No puedes hacer comparación DateTime vs INT, mas bien tienes que trasladar los dos campos al mismo formato.

Y hay dos posibles soluciones.

La primera una comparación con el DATEDIFF, te regresara la diferencia que tu le indiques entre las dos fechas, en este caso los meses de diferencia, y los igualamos a 0 para que regrese los registros que coincidan con ese mes únicamente.

```
SELECT (SUM(Puntos)) as Suma
FROM DB.dbo.mitabla 
WHERE Usuario  = 252 AND DATEDIFF(MONTH, Fecha, GETDATE())=0
```

La segunda Opción es validarlo por enteros, sacamos el mes de la fecha de tus registros y el mes de la fecha contra la que quieres validar, y pero adicional es recomendable agregar una validación similar para el año, por que si tu tabla incluye muchos años te traera ese mes de todos los años.

```
SELECT (SUM(Puntos)) as Suma
FROM DB.dbo.mitabla 
WHERE Usuario  = 252 AND YEAR(Fecha)= YEAR(GETDATE()) AND  MONTH(Fecha) =  YEAR(GETDATE())
```